# Table row escapes (became blank) after ComboBox field edit PySide6 (PyQt6 also)

Tags: python, sql-server, pyqt6

I have a table_view with several columns including 2 comboboxes. The table is connected to Azure SQL database table. If I try to update field with combobox database table updates correctly, but in view updated row became blank (all fields empty) and unavailable.
If I try to update other field (numeric for example) everything processing normally.
If azure table is not updated as a reason of database triggers or rules row also not escapes.

I tried PySide6 and PyQt6 libraries, but have the same result. The code is below

```
class PlayerComboBoxDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self, parent, player_names):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.player_names = player_names

    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        combo_box = QComboBox(parent)
        for player_id, last_name in self.player_names.items():
            combo_box.addItem(last_name, player_id)
        return combo_box

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        player_id = index.model().data(index, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)
        editor.setCurrentIndex(editor.findData(player_id))
        editor.setCurrentText(self.player_names.get(player_id, ""))

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        player_id = editor.currentData()
        model.setData(index, player_id, Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)

    def updateEditorGeometry(self, editor, option, index):
        editor.setGeometry(option.rect)
        self.setEditorData(editor, index)  # Update displayed text



class CustomTableModel(QSqlTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.player_names = self.load_player_names()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key.Key_Down and self.currentIndex().row() == self.model().rowCount() - 1:
            self.model().insertNewRecord()

    def load_player_names(self):
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT id, last_name FROM players")
        player_names = {}
        while query.next():
            player_id = query.value(0)
            last_name = query.value(1)
            player_names[player_id] = last_name
        return player_names
    
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and index.column() in (self.fieldIndex("player_1"), self.fieldIndex("player_2")):
            player_id = index.data(Qt.ItemDataRole.EditRole)
            return self.player_names.get(player_id, "")
        return super().data(index, role)
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 400)

        # Create a database connection
        conn_str = get_conn_str()
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QODBC")
        db.setDatabaseName(conn_str) 
        db.open()

        # Create a CustomTableModel for the main table
        self.pairs_model = CustomTableModel()
        self.pairs_model.setTable('cmp_pair_1')
        self.pairs_model.select()
        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setup_table_view()
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)


    def setup_table_view(self):
        self.table_view = QTableView()
        self.table_view.setModel(self.pairs_model)
        self.table_view.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)

        player1_idx = self.pairs_model.fieldIndex("player_1")
        player2_idx = self.pairs_model.fieldIndex("player_2")
        player_delegate = PlayerComboBoxDelegate(self, self.pairs_model.player_names)
        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(player1_idx, player_delegate)
        self.table_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(player2_idx, player_delegate)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.table_view)
    
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```